# Color harmonies math:triada, complement, analogous, monochromatic

Tags: color, color-theory

I need help in color math. I have one main color and i want to know how i can calculate other colors of chosen harmony. I need such color harmonies: triada, complement, analogous, monochromatic. Any help is appreciated. Thanks, Dima.

Comment: either way, this still isn't really a graphic design question. We're not typically known for our high-level math skills.

Comment: This was already asked on SO, but I think if we can offer at least methodologies for figuring this out, this can be on-topic.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This may still be better suited to SO, but we can answer it here.

To do the whole thing in code, you have to break down the different steps.  The basic process is to be able to calculate a specific hue at any point on the color wheel.  Your harmonies will be at specific offsets from your base point.  So if you can find your point on the wheel, and calculate the color of an arbitrary point, you'll have your answer.

Creating the color-wheel should be pretty straightforward.  Here are some other helpful links:

- [StackOverflow post with pseudo code on how to convert your RGB value to HSL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4235072/math-behind-the-colour-wheel)
- [Positions of common harmonies on the color wheel](http://www.easyrgb.com/index.php?X=WEEL)

Comment: Note that the SO's solution is from the easyRGB-site -- which turns out to be a great resource for some color math needs in pseudo code!